# Match up links with text using PyMuPDF?

Tags: python, pdf, pymupdf

I would like to extract text and links from PDF files using PyMuPDF. I have extracted the links using `page.get_links()` but what is the best method for matching the links with the text from `page.get_text()`?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can extract all the [`Rect`](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rect.html#rect) elements containing a *"uri"* and pass it to [`get_textbox`](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/annot.html#Annot.get_textbox) :

```
import fitz  # pymupdf

links = {}
with fitz.open("input.pdf") as doc:
    for page in doc:
        links[page.number + 1] = {
            page.get_textbox(d["from"]).strip("."): d["uri"]
            for d in page.get_links()
        }
```

Output :

```
{
    1: {
        "StackOverflow": "https://stackoverflow.com/",
        "Meta": "https://meta.stackoverflow.com/",
        "GIS Exchange": "https://gis.stackexchange.com/",
    }
}
```

Used (`input.pdf`) :

[image]

Comment: The problem with this method is that any text on the page that matches the text of a link will also be outputted as a link. So for example, if the word `Meta` shows up once as a link on a page, then any other mention of the word `Meta` on the same page will also be outputted as a link.

Comment: Are you sure about the behaviour you're describing ? I wonder if you have you done any *tests*. Anyways, you must show some effort (*just a bit*) and describe exactly your input pdf as well as your expected output ;).